# Android App web based html5 Music Source used with cordova -plugin-music-controls2 but no controls or music info on lock screen

Tags: android, cordova, html5-audio, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

I've been trying to make this plugin work on my app that plays music from an html5 web source server & not from the device,
https://github.com/ghenry22/cordova-plugin-music-controls2
when the html source is loaded to chrome on android it shows the music playing on the device's locked screen,
when the same html link is opened & played from the android app nothing shows on the locked screen,
i read that The Media Session API is supported in Chrome only, so is there a way to make it work in cordova android ?
by the way it works with no issues on the IOS side,
regards

Comment: Might help to open an issue with this question on GitHub https://github.com/ghenry22/cordova-plugin-music-controls2/issues

Comment: already did raise the issue there a week ago but no answer so far